# Show not displaying multiple ContourPlot3D's

Tags: plotting, options

I'm trying to make an image that looks like this:
[image]

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this is the relevant part of my code.

```
contourCurve = ContourPlot3D[
   {z == g[x, y], z == g[p, q]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.11, 1.7}, {z, 0, 3},
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[1]], 
     Directive[ Blue, Opacity[0]]},
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Brown, Gray}, #3] &),
   (*MeshStyle\[Rule]{1\[Rule] Gray,2\[Rule] None },*)
   Mesh -> None,
   BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> None, 1 -> None}
   ];
contourPlane = ContourPlot3D[
   {z == g[x, y], z == g[p, q]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.11, 1.7}, {z, 0, 3},
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0]], 
     Directive[ Blue, Opacity[0.4]]},
   (*MeshStyle\[Rule]{1\[Rule] Gray,2\[Rule] None },*)
   Mesh -> None,
   BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> { Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, 
     1 -> None}
   ];
Show[{
  Graphics3D[{
    centerPoint,
    surfNormArrow,
    gradArrow,
    tangArrow
    }],
  contourCurve,
  contourPlane
  },
 Axes -> False,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 Boxed -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{-0.75, 0.75}, {0.1, 2}, {0.1, 1}}
 ]
```

The above graphic was actually made with this code. However, after saving, reopening, and  reevaluating, I am only able to get one part of the graphic. So it looks like one of these two pictures, depending on if I list `contourCurve` or `contourPlane` first within the `Show` command.

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or I encountered some weird error. I'm also open to suggestions if there are better ways to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are the definitions of `g`, `p`, `q`, `centerPoint`, `surfNormArrow`, `gradArrow`, and `tangArrow`?

Comment: `f[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{1.75*Exp[-1/(1 - x^2 - y^2)], x^2 + y^2 < 1}, {0, x^2 + y^2 >= 1}}]; g[x_, y_] := f[1.1 x, 0.5 y];p = 0.0; q = 1.0;`  You can safely ignore the point and arrows. I get the same problem if I use `Show[{ contourPlane, contourCurve}]` .

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I have no idea why this works when my original code doesn't. All I had to do was switch the rules for `BoundaryStyle[... {1,2}->xxxx ...]`. So it should read like this:

```
contourCurve = ContourPlot3D[
   {z == g[x, y], z == g[p, q]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.11, 1.7}, {z, 0, 3},
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[1]], 
     Directive[ Blue, Opacity[0]]},
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Brown, Gray}, #3] &),
   (*MeshStyle\[Rule]{1\[Rule] Gray,2\[Rule] None },*)
   Mesh -> None,
   BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> { Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, 1 -> None}
   ];
contourPlane = ContourPlot3D[
   {z == g[x, y], z == g[p, q]},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.11, 1.7}, {z, 0, 3},
   ContourStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0]], 
     Directive[ Blue, Opacity[0.4]]},
   (*MeshStyle\[Rule]{1\[Rule] Gray,2\[Rule] None },*)
   Mesh -> None,
   BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> None, 
     1 -> None}
   ];
```